# VB.net txt to csv

Tags: vb.net

I am new in vb.net, i want to convert txt file to csv. I have txt file like this:

> ```
> Name
> A
> Class
> 10
> Roll No
> 123
> Name
> B
> Class
> 9
> Roll No
> 23
> Name
> C
> Class
> 7
> Roll No
> 3
> ```

How to export in csv file like this

```
A,10,123
B,9,23
c,7,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not well structured. It would be fine if it's XML. Try this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
  StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
  using (reader)
  {
    string line = "";
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        reader.ReadLine();  //Skip the name line
        string name = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.ReadLine();  //Skip the class line
        string cls = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.ReadLine();  //skip the rollup line
        string rollno = reader.ReadLine();

        csv.AppendLine(String.Join(",", new string[] { name, cls, rollno }));
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString());

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

OUPUT

```
A,10,123
B,9,23
C,7,3
```

Comment: thank you very much for the concept. This concept will work fine for me. wondering... why i get -3 for this question :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SearchString = Replace(SearchString, Chr(13), ",")
```